# Why is the Entity Framework Model Browser not displaying?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

In Visual Studio 2019 I am unable to see the EDMX Model Browser. When I right click on the diagram and click "Model Browser" the panel comes up blank/ transparent and nothing shows.

Comment: Bug and work around regisered here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578666/edmx-model-browser-not-working-in-version-161.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rendering related bug. The workaround is to go to the Visual Studio menu Tools -> Options and uncheck Envrionment->General->Optimize Rendering for Screens.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I just updated visual studio to 16.1.4 and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue hasn't been fixed after updating my Visual Studio to 16.9.2.

To remedy the issue, I just used Visual Studio 2017 instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the panel is opening up on the side bar just click on it and drag it as if you are making it a floating window. That fixes the rendering issue for me and I just dock it back.